# Save me from changing the look of CKEditor using Javascript

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I see that code is being rendered to produce this CKEditor (via the CKEditor module) contains an inline style that creates a height of 200 pixels. I'd like to change this value to 100px to save a bit of screen space.

[image]

I would like to change this or override this is a maintainable way. In the hopes it was in a tpl.php I tried `find . -name '*.php' -exec grep -lin 'presentation' {} \;` with little luck.

**Can anyone point me to where can override this value?** Or better put, how can I do better than this:

```
jQuery(function() {
        console.log('Resizing ckeditor')
        jQuery('#cke_1_contents').attr('style', 'height: 100px; max-height: 100px;');
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "value". You want to change the style of the `<div>`  element?

Comment: You should explain what you want to achieve and perhaps specify whether you are using the Wysiwyg or CKEditor module (in case it matters).

Comment: Are you trying to resize the height of the ckeditor?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to reduce the height of this element to 100px instead of 200px.

Comment: @othermachines, I'm using the CKEditor module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **CSS override** in your stylesheet to achieve this:

```
.cke_contents {
  max-height: 100px;
  height: 100px !important;
}
```

And, of course, if you only want to change one instance of the editor, just use an ID selector instead.

Comment: Would this take precedence over an inline style? I was under the assumption that inlines had the highest weight / priority? So far any changes that I made to the style sheets have not appeared to take any kind of effect -- even after drush cc all and clearing browser cache.

Comment: That's what !important is for.